# Will the Team Retrospective extension have a more permanent replacement with the Azure Devops platform?

Tags: azure-devops

My team uses the Team Retrospective extension & it's being un-published from the marketplace later this month. I'd love to know if Azure Devops will continue to support this extension and/or if it will be replaced as a new feature within the Azure Devops platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd love to know if Azure Devops will continue to support this extension and/or if it will be replaced as a new feature within the Azure Devops platform.

AFAIK, Azure Devops will continue to support this extension. I got following message:

> Retrospectives will be un-published from the Marketplace on May 29,
>   2020 Beginning on May 29th, 2020 the Team Retrospectives extension
>   will no longer be available on the Azure DevOps Marketplace. **Existing
>   installations will continue to work with the exception of the
>   real-time update feature, until your organization admin explicitly
>   removes the extension from the ADO tenant**. Thank you to everyone who
>   provided feedback for helping to improve the extension ecosystem.

So, if you have already installed this extension on your organization, it will continue to be supported.

Hope this helps.